# Does the Monero wallet distribute the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Does it send many blocks to other peers? If so how can I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the official Monero app (`monerod`) also helps the network by distributing the blockchain. This can be turned off by starting `monerod` with the `--hide-my-port` argument.

If you haven't set up port-forwarding in your router, most likely you will not distribute the blockchain. You can check how many nodes are connected to your daemon by issuing the following command inside the `monerod` prompt: `status`.
This shows something like this:

`Height: [...], 8(out)+30(in) connections [...]`

The number in front of `(in)` indicates the number of incoming connections. If this is `0` for you, nobody is connected to your node which means you're not distributing the blockchain.